# XPath for Maven POM

Tags: java, xml, xpath, pom.xml

Im looking at a way of querying an `XML` file and it seems that `XPath` is recommended quite alot. The only problem is I cant find any documentation on how to import this into my maven pom. Does anyone know the details?

Comment: There's a 1.0 implementation in the standard Java SE [javax.xml.xpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) package from Java 5 onwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

see http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/

Comment: There is now a new version (2.7.2). Check https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xalan/xalan to find the newest one.